# After doing a pull in git, these updates show to me as changes to commit

Tags: git, pull

Hy,

I am having a strange behaviour after doing a pull in git. I have seen that the updates I got from my workmate after the pull,  showed to me as changes to commit and I dont know why this could happen. I am using git in windows

Thanks

Comment: Is there a conflict?  Run `git status` and see if any files say "Both modified"

Comment: Maybe, this is an issue with line-endings in windows. Do these files look the same, but git says they have all lines deleted and added again? Then, it could help to set `core.autocrlf=false`